# Поиск по подкатологам

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть код

```
bool find()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA fdFindData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFileA("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\*", &fdFindData);
    while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &fdFindData))
    {
        printf("%s ", fdFindData.cFileName);
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return 1;
}
```

Но он ищет только файлы в Desktop, как я могу пройтись ещё по подкатологам?

Comment: Во-первых возвращаемые значения всегда следует проверять на предмет ошибки. Во-вторых следует использовать W варианты функций. В третьих тут поиск происходит не только по файлам, но и по каталогам соответственно ничего не мешает вызывать эту функцию рекурсивно для каждого найденного подкаталога.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA fdFindData;
```

есть такое поле - `dwFileAttributes`, которое показывает, в частности, а не каталог ли это

```
if (fdFindData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {...
```

так что, встретив каталог, вы можете рекурсивно пройтись в поисках файлов по нему.

С другой стороны, раз у вас C++, то можно воспользоваться такой штукой, как [`std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) и не мучиться.